# Subgroups of $S_4$ (proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

How do I prove that $S_4$ has a subgroup of order $d$ for every factor $d$ of $24$?

Hence, $S_4$ must have eight subgroups with orders $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$.

It's clear that $\{e\}$ is a subgroup of order $1$ but how do I prove the other seven subgroups?

Answer (score 2):

$\langle (1) \rangle$ has order $1$.

$\langle (12) \rangle$ has order $2$.

$\langle (123) \rangle$ has order $3$.

$\langle (1234) \rangle$ has order $4$.

$S_3$ has order $6$.

$A_4$ has order $12$.

$S_4$ has order $24$.

It remains to find a group of order $8$. That is $D_8$, the symmetries of the square.